# Why doesn't makeLenses derive a lens for some quantified constructors?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, gadt

I'm trying to make lenses for a slightly complex GADT, and finding it doesn't want to generate one for one of my constructors. The code looks like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes, TemplateHaskell, KindSignatures, DataKinds #-}

import Control.Lens
import GHC.TypeNats

data Variant (m :: Nat) where
  VariantA :: Variant 42

data Stuff where
  Foo :: { _foo :: Int } -> Stuff
  Bar :: forall t. { _bar :: String } -> Stuff
  Baz :: forall m. { _baz :: Variant m } -> Stuff

$(makeLenses ''Stuff)
```

I find that this generates lenses `foo` and `bar`, but not `baz`. It seems to be something to do with the constraint on `baz` and the kind signature `Variant m`. Why can't I get a lens for `baz`?

I saw that some support for existentially quantified record constructors was added at the end of https://github.com/ekmett/lens/issues/409, but wondering if this is a further `lens` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with `makeLenses`. The problem is that you really *can't* write a `Traversal`, or even a `Setter`, for `_baz`. Let's see what happens when you try to write a `Traversal`:

```
baz :: Traversal' Stuff (Variant m)
baz f (Baz v) = _
baz _f s = pure s
```

GHC says:

```
LensGADT.hs:19:17: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: f Stuff
      Where: ‘f’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 baz :: forall (m :: Nat). Traversal' Stuff (Variant m)
               at LensGADT.hs:18:1-35
    • In the expression: _
      In an equation for ‘baz’: baz f (Baz v) = _
    • Relevant bindings include
        v :: Variant m1 (bound at LensGADT.hs:19:12)
        f :: Variant m -> f (Variant m) (bound at LensGADT.hs:19:5)
        baz :: (Variant m -> f (Variant m)) -> Stuff -> f Stuff
          (bound at LensGADT.hs:19:1)
      Constraints include Applicative f (from LensGADT.hs:18:1-35)
   |
19 | baz f (Baz v) = _
   |                 ^
```

You see the problem? We're given a function of type `Variant m -> f (Variant m)` for some `m`, and we have a value of type `Variant m1`, for some (possibly different) `m1`. We can't possibly apply the function! Exactly the same problem shows up if you try to write a setter.

The best you could do is this:

```
baz1 :: Applicative f => (forall m. Variant m -> f (Variant m)) -> Stuff -> f Stuff
baz1 f (Baz v) = Baz <$> f v
baz1 _f s = pure s
```

or this (same code, slightly different type):

```
baz2 :: Applicative f => (forall m. Variant m -> f (Variant n)) -> Stuff -> f Stuff
baz2 f (Baz v) = Baz <$> f v
baz2 _f s = pure s
```

These are very much like traversals, but they're certainly not `Traversal`s in the `lens` sense. Moreover, neither of them is strictly more general than the other, and a more flexible version that subsumes both will look significantly less like a `Traversal`. So it doesn't seem that reasonable for `makeLenses` to even try.